# swift trigonometric functions (cos, tan, arcsin, arcos, arctan)

Tags: swift, degrees, trigonometry, radians

I have to differenciate calculations in degrees and I have the following code, but it doesn't return me the exact values. The only one right is the value of sin90 in degree = 1

```
//////***** DEGREES ******//////
var sinus = sin(90.0 * M_PI / 180)
var cosinus = cos(90 * M_PI / 180)
var tangent = tan(90 * M_PI / 180)

var arcsinus = asin(90 * M_PI / 180)
var arcosinus = acos(90 * M_PI / 180)
var arctangent = atan(90 * M_PI / 180)
```

What is the right operation to return the exact value for every operation in degrees for cos, tan and their ARC functions?

Comment: `sin` and the rest take _angle in radians_ as an argument.  Why do you do this `90 * 180 / M_PI` stuff in the latter part?

Comment: could you write your answer in a piece of code for the value of 90? because I dont really get what you mean .. :) sorry I am new @AntonBronnikov

Comment: 90 * 180 / M_PI is the transformation from rad to degree.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is more a math problem than a Swift problem:

```
let sinus = sin(90.0 * Double.pi / 180)
print("Sinus \(sinus)")

let cosinus = cos(90 * Double.pi / 180)
print("Cosinus \(cosinus)")

let tangent = tan(90 * Double.pi / 180)
print("Tangent \(tangent)")
```

prints

```
Sinus 1.0
Cosinus 6.12323399573677e-17
Tangent 1.63312393531954e+16
```

Sinus of 90 degrees is 1 (correct)

Cosinus of 90 degrees is 0. The value 6e-17 is a very very small value, any sensible rounding would consider it equal to zero (correct). The fact that you can't get exactly zero is due to rounding errors in the calculation.

Tangent of 90 degrees is not defined (sin/tan = 1/0, division by zero is not defined). If we had precise calculations, you would probably get an infinity. In this case we have `1` divided by `6e-17`, which becomes a large number `1.6e16`. The result is correct.

Regarding the inverse functions, note one thing - their parameters are neither in degrees or radians. Their result is in degrees/radians, for example:

```
let arcsinus = asin(1.0) * 180 / Double.pi
print("Arcsinus \(arcsinus)")
```

prints

```
Arcsinus 90.0
```

Comment: so, I do not have to change something? My code is right as it is ?
@Sulthan? Any way to return and display the right value on the display?

Comment: @kepi Your results are correct, to display them to users, you have to convert them to strings, first. I would recommend `NSNumberFormatter` which will handle rounding and formatting for you.

Comment: ok @sulthan! 
Again, I am new so I do not really understand how to implement this NSNumberFormatter ?

Comment: @kepi There are multiple examples over the internet and stack overflow. Please, search first.

Comment: What framework you import to access all these function?

Comment: @Tushar-iOSdeveloper If you import `Foundation`, you will have access to all common math functions and constants.

Answer (score 14):

Swift 4 works out with a modified syntax:

```
let sinus = sin(90.0 * Double.pi / 180)
let cosinus = cos(90 * Double.pi / 180)
let tangent = tan(90 * Double.pi / 180)

let arcsinus = asin(1) * 180/ Double.pi
let arcosinus = acos(0) * 180/ Double.pi
let arctangent = atan(1) * 180/ Double.pi
```